# How to control and monitor processes in remote host with supervisor?

Tags: supervisord

`Supervisor` document mentions about `remote command line`.

> Supervisor provides you with one place to start, stop, and monitor
>   your processes. Processes can be controlled individually or in groups.
>   You can configure Supervisor to provide a local or remote command line
>   and web interface.

Does it mean that `supervisor` can control and monitor processes running on a remote host?

For example,

1. There are three servers `A`, `B` and `C`.
2. Server `A` run supervisor.
3. The supervisor run processes in `B` and `C`.
4. The supervisor can monitor and control(stop and start) the processes in `B` and `C`.

If it is possible, could you give me a Supervisor config example for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use supervisor only to manage remote host's process.

but you can install supervisor on each host, and manage them on a control host by using [supervisor XML-RPC API](http://supervisord.org/api.html), which is official.

and many plugins are implemented in this way.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the quote is not 100% clear. IMHO it means the control can happen remotely or local.

Anyway found this part of the supervisor documentation very helpful.
http://supervisord.org/plugins.html

It mentions tools that can help you control supervisor on multiple machine from single source.

Answer (score 0):

use xml-rpc

```py
import socket
from http.client import HTTPConnection
from xmlrpc import client


class UnixStreamHTTPConnection(HTTPConnection):
    def connect(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect(self.host)


class UnixStreamTransport(client.Transport, object):
    def __init__(self, socket_path):
        self.socket_path = socket_path
        super(UnixStreamTransport, self).__init__()

    def make_connection(self, host):
        return UnixStreamHTTPConnection(self.socket_path)


server = client.ServerProxy('http://127.0.0.1',transport=UnixStreamTransport("/path/to/supervisor.sock"))
print(proxy.supervisor.getState())
server.supervisor.stopProcess("test")
server.supervisor.startProcess("test")
```